# Bottle server to accept question mark as input in Python

Tags: python, web, input, server, bottle

I am writing the following code:

`from bottle import route, run
@route('/input/')
def greet(name):
    return name`

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)

However, when I try to access like this:
http://localhost:8080/input/?Hi

I get the following error:
Sorry, the requested URL 'http://localhost:8080/input/?Hi' caused an error:
Not found: '/input/'

I need to parse the whole string "?Hi" as an input string in my method "inpout"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to replicate your issue, but have not had success. What version of bottle are you using?

Below is a slightly altered version of your code to have it print "hello (name)" with a GET variable.

```
from bottle import route, run, request

@route('/input/')
def greet():
    return "hello " + request.query.get("name")


run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Hitting `http://localhost:8080/input/?name=shaklasah` will result in `hello shaklasah`